# RedShift: JSON_PARSE() error: End-of-input during string sequence

Tags: amazon-redshift

Maybe someone has, or knows what could be.

In general, I make such a request to RedShift:

```
SELECT JSON_PARSE(inputs) AS inputs_super
FROM table
WHERE prompttype = 'input' AND (inputs IS NOT NULL OR inputs != 'null')
ORDER BY created
OFFSET 1000
LIMIT 1;
```

I get this mistake:

```
ERROR: Invalid input 
Detail: 
----------------------------------------------- 
error: Invalid input 
code: 8001 
context: JSON_PARSE() error: End-of-input during string sequence: (16372 bytes skipped) 0303)|(9550 
query: 30091521 
location: partiql_parser.cpp:794 
process: query1_99_30091521 [pid=19776] 
-----------------------------------------------
```

I’m trying to figure out what the base line is to find the problem. I make this request:

```
SELECT inputs FROM table
WHERE prompttype = 'input' AND (inputs IS NOT NULL OR inputs != 'null')
ORDER BY created
OFFSET 1000
LIMIT 1;
```

I get this result:

```
[{"desc": "In your opinion, do you think that the script you have just recorded were natural?", "name": "Survey", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["YES", "NO"]}]
```

I try to check this line separately in JSON_PARSE:

```
SELECT JSON_PARSE('[{"desc": "In your opinion, do you think that the script you have just recorded were natural?", "name": "Survey", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["YES", "NO"]}]');
```

I get a normal answer.

So, why does the first request send out an error if the data are essentially the same in the first and third cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue.

The main problem is that `ORDER BY` doesn't guarantee that I get the same string for each time, so I can't find a row with invalid string.

Answer (score 0):

This error is often caused by a `varchar` column being truncated such that when `json_parse` attempts to parse the record, it finds an incomplete JSON string which it fails to parse and prints the error you see.

The simplest solution is

```
alter table alter column inputs type varchar(65535)
```

Where `varchar(65535)` is the maximum size varchar in Redshift.

**To find the problematic record**, you need to interpret the error message. Specifically this final part

```
(16372 bytes skipped) 0303)|(9550
```

This tells you what the problematic record looked like. Concretely, that after 16372 bytes (which were skipped), the string ended with `0303)|(9550`. Knowing this, we can write a query like the one below which will return the raw string(s) Redshift could not parse.

```
select len(inputs), inputs, *
from table
where inputs like '%0303)|(9550%'
order by len(inputs) desc
```

If `table` is a spectrum table, you can add `select len(inputs), inputs, "$path" ...` to get the file containing the problematic record.